# Unable to delete column with cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am not able to delete the column with all the cells. It works fine if i try to delete the last column but if i try to delete the column before last, it does not work as expected.

This is how my HTML looks like:

```
        <table id="tblData">
            <thead>
                <tr style="background-color:green" id="trMain">
                    <th>Fixed 1</th>
                    <th>Fixed 2</th>
                    <th>Fixed 3</th>
                    <th id="Collection1">Collection 1</th>
                    <th id="Collection2">Collection 2</th>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color:red" id="trSub">
                    <th>E1</th>
                    <th>E2</th>
                    <th>E3</th>
                    <th>
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>P1</th>
                                    <th>P2</th>
                                    <th>P3</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>P1</th>
                                    <th>P2</th>
                                    <th>P3</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>


<button type="button" id="btnGet">Delete a Column</button>
```

This is how my JS looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var colToDelete = 'Collection2';
    $('#btnGet').click(function(){

            var column = $("#tblData").find('#' + colToDelete);
            var row = column.parent('tr').children();
            var idx = row.index(column);
            alert(idx)
            $("#trMain").find("th:eq(" + idx + ")").remove();
            alert(idx)
            $("#trSub").find("th:eq(" + idx + ")").remove();

    });
});
```

Here is the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cH654/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have updated your script, this should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var colToDelete = 'del1';
$('#btnGet').click(function(){

        var column = $("#tblData").find('#' + colToDelete);
        var row = column.parent('tr').children();
        var idx = row.index(column);
        $("#trMain").find("th:eq(" + idx + ")").remove();
        $("#trSub > th:eq(" + idx + ")").remove();

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problems because you put a table within a table, so the columns of your two rows doesn't correspond. Your second row should be like this:

```
<tr style="background-color:red" id="trSub">
      <th>E1</th>
      <th>E2</th>
      <th>E3</th>
      <th>P1 P2 P3</th>
      <th>P1 P2 P3</th>
</tr>
```

And your jquery function should be as simple as this:

```
$('#btnGet').click(function(){
     $("#trMain th").last().remove();
     $("#trSub th").last().remove();     
});
```

Here is working: http://jsfiddle.net/cH654/5/

Comment: the reason i put P1 P2 P3 in separate table is because i want them as Columns. They are 3 different columns inside a Collection. Like Matrix.